# Best Practice For 'Recent Activities of My Friends'

Tags: facebook

What are the best practice for making 'Recent Activities of My Friends' in websites such as FriendFeed or Facebook sites... How can these data stored and queried? Is there any publisher/ subscriber technology or something else?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're much more likely to get an answer if you provide more details. For instance, it seems likely you'll be using a database. MySQL? Oracle?

Language? PHP? Perl? Python? Tell us more.

Answer (score 0):

We are using MySQL and our primary language is Java.

I have no idea such an architecture how it is build.

For example, a user with a 100 friend, should notify all of friends. Each friend should see recent activities of his friends also. However, I am not sure whether users should have their own history or not. What is the best practice for this?

Comment: Please edit your original question instead of posting an answer.  Thanks.